# Given 3 series merge to create a new series with 1 column containing numbers of each dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have 3 series with data like below

```
s1 = [1,1,3]
s2 = [2,3,2]
s3 = [4,2,1]
```

I want to create a new series with values such that

`s_new = [124,132,321]`

please note that `s_new = int(''.join(s1,s2,s3))`
I know the above syntax is wrong but you get the idea.

Comment: Ok I found a way to scale them like so.
s1 = s1.apply(lambda x: x*100)
s2 = s2.apply(lambda x:x*10)
but now the question remains to s1 s2 and s3 to get s_new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with pandas `agg`

```
s = pd.DataFrame([s1,s2,s3]).astype(str).agg(''.join).astype(int).tolist()
Out[334]: [124, 132, 321]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s1 = [1,1,3]
s2 = [2,3,2]
s3 = [4,2,1]
matrix = [s1,s2,s3]
s_new = ["" for x in range(len(matrix))];

for i in range(0,len(matrix)):
    for j in range(0,len(matrix[i])):
        s_new[i]+=str(matrix[j][i])
        
print(s_new)
```

unfortunately, I am not pyton programmer but this algo still works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy

```
import numpy as np


s1 = [1, 1, 3]
s2 = [2, 3, 2]
s3 = [4, 2, 1]

s4 = [int("".join(str(i) for i in x)) for x in np.column_stack([s1, s2, s3])]
print(s4)

[124, 132, 321]
```